# Is there a way in sbt to convert compiler warnings to errors so the build fails?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to "ban" some or all compiler warnings.

Comment: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/04/11/scalac-flags.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can pass options from sbt to the scala compiler, including the one that turns warnings into errors.

I usually add these:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature", "-Xfatal-warnings"),
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the [scalac options documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html), you can pass either `-Werror` or `-Xfatal-warnings`.
You can do that in sbt by appending to `scalacOptions`.

```scala
scalacOptions += "-Werror"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at fatal-warnings scalac flag.

Source:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/simple-build-tool/RcDnib_EGL4