# Why is a a deprecation warning causing a compile error in SBT

Tags: java, scala, sbt

The project I'm working on uses Scala and SBT.  I need to introduce the use of a deprecated method in our code and rather than just giving me an error, sbt is giving me a compile error when I try and compile the code.

Is there a flag or setting somewhere that makes this happen that I can change?

```
method getDB in class Mongo is deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc 
for more information.
[error]   lazy val db: com.mongodb.DB = mongoClient.getDB("foo")
[error]                                             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (web/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Jun 2, 2017 7:20:53 AM
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SBT gives you a lot of options to set depreciation warnings as errors.

```
set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-Xfatal-warnings")
```

OR

```
sbt compile -deprecation
```

OR

You can configure the same in build.sbt file.

You'll have to remove any of the above options if you are using. (Check your compiler settings)

Also, do `sbt clean reload compile`.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Scalac has a flag `Xfatal-warnings` that turns warnings into errors. See [Is there a way in sbt to convert compiler warnings to errors so the build fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624236/is-there-a-way-in-sbt-to-convert-compiler-warnings-to-errors-so-the-build-fails) and https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8410

A workaround is defining a deprecated trait that calls the method and making its companion object implement that trait:

```
scala> @deprecated("","") def foo = "I am deprecated"
foo: String

scala> @deprecated("","") trait Foo { def safeFoo = foo }; object Foo extends Foo
defined trait Foo
defined object Foo

scala> foo
<console>:13: warning: method foo is deprecated:
       foo
       ^
res0: String = I am deprecated

scala> Foo.safeFoo
res1: String = I am deprecated
```

Comment: That flag was actually set in my build.sbt but I've removed it and I still get the compile error.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the error that you get?

Comment: @Kohl Did you reload the sbt configuration after the change (restart sbt or type reload at the sbt prompt)?

Comment: @jan0sch beat me to it by a second.

Comment: Interesting work around.  Is there a way to disable this check in configuration though?  I have another SBT project that doesn't have this same problem.

Comment: @jan0sch I have restarted SBT several times after removing that scalacOption.  I also deleted all target directories and recompiled for good measure.  Still see the error

Comment: @Kohl Possibly you have a multi-project build and didn't remove `-Xfatal-warnings` from the offending subproject but from another one?

Comment: I did "grep -r fatal-warnings" from the root of my project and nothing comes up.  Is there some way to see which scalac options are actually getting used in sbt?

Comment: `show [subproject]/scalacOptions` per subproject. Don't know if you can automatically list for all subprojects at once. Maybe you have some compilerplugin that turns warnings into errors...

Comment: Wow, yep the setting is there when I run show but I've removed all references to it in my project.  As mentioned above a grep for fatal-warnings' doesn't return anything.

Comment: I honestly don't know how that can happen.

Comment: Is there anyway to see where all of the scalacOptions are getting set?  It seems like some of the dependencies that I pull in end up pulling in other scalacOptions.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.sbt you can set scalaOptions as below :

```
lazy val exScalacOptions: Seq[String] = Seq(
  "-Xlint",
  "-feature",
  "-deprecation:false",
  "-unchecked"
)
```

After setting the above value you can reference it in your project module settings in `build.sbt` as below:

```
scalacOptions := exScalacOptions
```